vue-yandex-maps: 2.1.4 Как задать z-index для clusterer
Большое спасибо, что устранили баг с исчезновение кластеров при перемещении карты. Вопрос: как задать z-index для компонента clusterer декларативно?

Всем спасибо, нашёл: параметр clusterMarkerProps.
